# Control marker visibility by zoom level Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

From the backend I receive data with locations, then I show them on the map. How can I make it so that on the map, depending on the zoom, the number of markers changes, and when you get closer, so that the number increases?

```
<GoogleMap zoom={zoom} center={center} mapContainerClassName="map-container"
            options={{
                restriction: {
                    latLngBounds: azerbaijanBounds,
                    strictBounds: false,
                },
            }}
        >
            {counter && data && data.map((loc) => (
                <div key={loc.id} className="custom-marker-wrapper">
                    <Marker
                        position={{ lat: loc.location[0], lng: loc.location[1] }}
                        onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(loc)}
                        icon={'data:image/png;base64,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'}
                    >
                        {loc.isOpen && loc.title && (
                            <InfoWindowF onCloseClick={() => handleMarkerClose(loc)}>
                                <div className='infoWindowDiv' onClick={(e) => { window.open(`https://example.com/item/${offerType}/${loc.id}`) }}>
                                    <span className='infoWindowTitle'>{loc.title}</span>
                                    <span className='infoWindowInfo'>Qiymet - <span className='infoWindowPrice'>{loc.price} AZN</span></span>
                                    <span className='infoWindowInfo'>Sahə - <span className='infoWindowPrice'>{loc.area} m <sup><small>2</small></sup></span></span>
                                    <span className='infoWindowInfo'>1kv/qiymet - <span className='infoWindowPrice'>{Math.round(loc.m2)} AZN</span></span>
                                </div>
                            </InfoWindowF>
                        )}
                    </Marker>
                </div>
            ))}
        </GoogleMap >
```

I tried to add class names in order to change the display values depending on the distance but it didn’t work

Comment: Hello! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on what you have tried so far so that the community can modify it and work on your concerns. If I'm understanding this correctly, you want to use Marker Clustering. Is that correct? There's available tutorial on it online (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VJTh7OqoJI), and also an existing library to do it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-google-maps/marker-clusterer

Answer (score 0):

I just sort relative to one point, then depending on the zoom I change the state

```
const groupMarkers = ((locations, zoom) => {
    const groupingThreshold = 0.5 / Math.pow(2, zoom / 2);
    const groupedMarkers = [];
    const sortByLocation = (properties, lat, lng) => {
        return properties?.sort((a, b) => {
            const distanceA = calculateDistance(a.location[0], a.location[1], lat, lng);
            const distanceB = calculateDistance(b.location[0], b.location[1], lat, lng);
            return distanceA - distanceB;
        });
    }
    const calculateDistance = (lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) => {
        const earthRadius = 6371;
        const radLat1 = (Math.PI * lat1) / 180;
        const radLat2 = (Math.PI * lat2) / 180;
        const deltaLat = (Math.PI * (lat2 - lat1)) / 180;
        const deltaLng = (Math.PI * (lng2 - lng1)) / 180;
        const a = Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLat / 2) + Math.cos(radLat1) * Math.cos(radLat2) * Math.sin(deltaLng / 2) * Math.sin(deltaLng / 2);
        const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
        const distance = earthRadius * c;
        return distance;
    }
    const sortedProperties = sortByLocation(locations, 40.317574, 50.339039);
    for (let i = 0; i < sortedProperties?.length - 1; i++) {
        if ((Math.abs(sortedProperties[i].location[0] - sortedProperties[i + 1].location[0])) > groupingThreshold && (Math.abs(sortedProperties[i].location[1] - sortedProperties[i + 1].location[1])) > groupingThreshold) {
            groupedMarkers.push(sortedProperties[i]);
        }
    }
    setData2(groupedMarkers)
})
```